Memory-Efficient Techniques for Directory/File Hierarchies with Fast Node Retrieval (C/C++)
My problem is as follows: I'd like to represent a directory/files-type structure in memory as efficiently as possible. By efficient, I mean:

Quick retrieval of siblings and children from paths like "d/local/pictures/birds/".
Compact memory usage. I know I can use pointers in a structure like this:

struct node {
    struct node* parent;
    struct node* child;
    struct node* siblings;
    const char* name;
    ...
};

However, my goal is to see if there's an alternative approach that could be better memory-wise, as I can have hundreds of thousands of such nodes.
I know I can use a hash table to efficiently store and retrieve a node by its full path, like so:
struct node* const node = find_hash_table(hash_table, "root/d/local/pictures/birds/beach_island/2021/pelican.0010.png");

And that's fine. But I also need to be able to retrieve a node's children and siblings. I can store the parent node's pointer (which I can use to calculate the hash key in my hash table by combining the parent's memory address with the hash key calculated using the current node's name). This approach allows me to rebuild the path by walking up to the root from a given location, but it doesn't allow me to build the tree by walking down from the root (at least not efficiently).
Another consideration is that I need to handle possible re-ordering of the tree/file structure, such as moving the birds directory under an animals directory. I was thinking about using index arrays to store the indices of a node's siblings and children, using a few tables to encode the offsets of children and siblings within a flat array. However, this approach is not well-suited when users manipulate the tree (as opposed to using pointers, where it only requires a single update) because I'd then need to update all values of all nodes affected by the change.
Can you point me to techniques that would allow me to achieve this (or approach this)?

Do you need predictably quick? Or is 'usually' quick acceptable to you? Because the latter can often be achieved with MRU caches to avoid the need for a full hash table.

Likewise, how quick is 'quick'. Do you really need a sibling pointer, or can you get away with looking up siblings by looking up the parent and then looking at its children?

Your struct node example shows a binary tree. You can usually get significant space + time improvements by using some variant of b-trees instead (storing multiple entries per tree node). Most file systems and database storage engines use b-trees, though write heavy applications will prefer LSM trees. Hash tables sound better, but at scale suffer issues relating to collisions and data locality. Using the entire path as hash key would also make it difficult to move a sub-tree around.

For when you need to go through the entire tree, tree walk algorithms are your friend not path lookups. And random access? Hopefully the lower ranked nodes will be cached and can be found by recursive prefix search, otherwise that's where the 'usually' comes in. It depends if the access pattern is truly uniform across a uniform tree, or if there are hotspots.

You can't take the siblings pointer out of the current scheme, because the parent only knows its first child, and getting to the rest of the children requires following the linked list.  Of course, storing the children using a different data structure (such as red-black tree aka std::map) at each parent could help performance, and then the sibling pointer becomes redundant.

@amon the struct node* children would be a linked list. So not really a binary tree. Sorry I should have mentioned this.

hundreds of thousands of such nodes  Memory is usually measured in gigabytes - 10 digits.  "[H]undreds of thousands of such nodes" is 6 digits.  There will likely be three or four orders of magnitude more memory available than you need.  Now, if your target platform is something like a small embedded system, then you will need to address every byte of memory used.  And certainly trying to be more efficient is a good goal.  But worrying about trying to save what's likely to be a few tens of kilobytes of memory when multiple gigabytes are available seems to be a premature optimization.

Another consideration: memory granularity.  When you use dynamic allocation (C's malloc() or C++ new), the underlying implementation often provides memory in discrete-sized chunks, such as 16, 32, or 64 bytes - if you ask for 12, you de facto get 16, if you ask for 33, you de facto get 64.  So reducing the size of a dynamically-allocated data structure from 60 bytes to 36 bytes could wind up saving you nothing in reality.  Note that such considerations will be highly implementation dependent, though.  You've asked a question with some pretty substantial implications.

Lets do some changes to your design. First of all you are dealing with a directed graph, likely acyclic (although it doesn't matter that much). Nodes have additional data attached, but that's not really that relevant.
So first of all, instead of keeping all of the data on a node, I would suggest you define a filesystem (or in simpler terms: a graph) first. And then define nodes to be simply... integers:
struct Node {
    int id;
}

struct NodeData {
    char* name;  // or better: std::string
}

struct Graph {
    vector<NodeData> node_data;
    vector<vector<Node>> children;
}

So id corresponds to the index in both node_data and children vectors. Retrieveing children is trivial:
const &vector<Node> get_children(const Graph& graph, Node node) {
    return &graph.children[node.id];
}

Finding a parent is of course O(n) here, but we can cache parents via another vector<Node> if necessary (since each node has only one parent, this is a very efficient flat representation - you can't do better). And finding siblings is a simple manner of retrieveing children of the parent. Caching siblings is a waste of memory, it won't be worth it.
Retrieval of nodes by path has to be done through some map (which would be an additional field on the graph). A tree of hash maps (e.g. a Radix tree) sounds like a good choice here. But plain flat hash map is good as well - hundreds of thousands of elements is not big enough to worry about collisions.
This data structure is almost the best you can do in terms of compact memory usage and fast access. There is still a room for optimization, e.g. if each node has small number of children, then we can use an "inline" variant of the inner vector<Node> in children. And use the actual heap allocated vector only above some threshold.
This will work insanely efficiently if you only add to the graph. However removal and structure modification (moving around nodes) will be either slow (updating entire vectors) or space consuming (instead of deleting data, only mark it as deleted and ignore when scanning, which also requires an additional sweep step at some point).
If you want to support fast addition, removal, search and iteration at the same time, then I suggest you implement some B+ tree as a replacement for children vector of vectors.
As a simple alternative to B+ trees you could use a skip list. This data structure is expected to perform exceptionally well most of the time. It is very cache and memory friendly. And easy to implement, unlike some B+ tree algorithms (especially when thread safety is required). The downside is that it can occasionally behave suboptimally. It is a probabilistic data structure after all. And also I've read some claims that some B+ trees outperform it. But even if, then I doubt the difference is big, and you need to be an expert in data structures to be able to implement those highly optimized B+ trees. Note that I did use skip list in production and I have not experienced any issues with it. Performance was great.
So why did I bother with explaining the primitive vector variant? For educational purposes, sure. But also because of the design. Look how simple it is: just switch one field to B+ tree. With the design you proposed this would be extremely hard. Always try to make designs easy to modify.

Great answers. I am constrained to using C but implementing equivalent structures to those of C++ you are referencing (vector etc.) is not big deal. Thanks I will look into all the pointers you gave. and BTW yes it's a DAG. I will implement these ideas and will come back with some feedback.
